# Do I have to jack up the car to replace the valve core?

Tags: toyota, tires, echo

I have a sticky tire valve core that needs to be fixed, but I don't have a nice garage to jack up the car (2004 Toyota Echo) and take the wheel off (I park on the street and it's at least -15C out).

Do I really have to jack the car up, and/or take the wheel off to replace it?

Comment: What exactly are you working on (make/model/year/engine)? By "core" what are you talking about? As it stands, this question is bound to be closed just on the lack of information and coherency.

Comment: Sorry, I only had the tire tag, but didn't mention that it's the tire valves. It's sticking open, and I could fix it by replacing the tire valve cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to jack up the car to change out the valve core. Make sure to have your replacement core at the ready. When you pull one core out, insert the other core. Some of the air in the tire will come out, of course, but you won't cause any damage to the tire. Stick your new core into the valve stem and tighten it. You may want to wear some nitrile or latex gloves while you are doing this. The air coming out of the tire will be cold, colder in fact than the outside air temperature. This could cause spots of frost bite on your finger tips if exposed to the escaping air for too long. The gloves will protect them well enough while you do your work.

You do need to know if the vehicle is equipped with a Tire Pressure Monitoring System (TPMS), though. Some of these have different valve cores than the normal cores, so replace with the right kind.

Comment: Thankfully the car is way too old to have a TPMS, so I should be in the clear.

Good call on the gloves. It's already cold out and the last thing I'd want is to frostnip my fingers :)

Comment: Worked like a charm. No more sticking valves. Now let's see if the new ones hold their pressure longer.